# How to add multiple controls inside a Frame in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am new to silverlight. I have to add multiple controls in a Navigation Frame. When i do like this ,i am getting error.

```
<Navigation:Frame Name="ContentFrame" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,55,12,12" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="5">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,129,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="UserName:" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,22,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Password:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
        </Navigation:Frame>
```

The Error is **The property 'Content' cannot be set more than once**. Where i am wrong. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Frame` is a `ContentControl` which means that it can only have a single child. You need to add a child control that is able to hold multiple children. Try a `Grid` for example:

```
<Navigation:Frame >
   <Grid>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,129,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="UserName:" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,22,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Password:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
   </Grid>
</Navigation:Frame>
```